# How to hard code data in relation in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

> > I want to hard code a small static dataset in my pig script. Basically i cant create file for this small dataset.  what is the
> >     right way to do it?

Comment: If the dataset is small then you can use %declare.For example %declare MY_DATA  '1|A|X,2|B|Y,3|C|Z';

Answer (score -1):

[Installing and Using HCatalog](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-2-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_19.html)

Apache HCatalog provides table data access for CDH components such as Pig and MapReduce.